# TestFlight Alternatives for Android

Tags: android, ios, testflight, over-the-air

Does anyone have suggestions for alternatives for TestFlight that works on Android or iOS?  This became more important since TestFlight announced it is dropping support for Android.

Comment: u ment to just share ur android build through url or u are looking for a analytics system for android?

Comment: Just curious: what is wrong with TestFlight?

Comment: @Jonik it is dropping support for Android

Comment: Oh, really? Any reference for that?

Comment: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1450414

Comment: I think this should not be closed, it is ON topic, and relevant in regards to the announcement referenced here (and I modified the question to be more relevant).   I don't know how to vote 'on-topic'

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407908/testflight-for-android-apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need something like test flight for Android, as there is nothing special required to install an Android app on multiple devices.  There is no concept of provisioning, etc.

You can install any Android App (packaged as an APK) on basically any Android device or emulator by copying it onto the device, and running the install command on it.

So, instead of TestFlight, you just need to provide a location to download your APK (basically from anywhere).  You could make it available in a Dropbox folder, on a website (either something you create, or maybe the output page of your Jenkins\CI Server), via thumb drive, or even email the APK.

Bottom line, because Android does not have the same packaging restrictions as iOS, it is much easier to distribute test builds, so TestFlight (or equivalent), is not really necessary.

Comment: Or just putting it on any web server with the correct "Content-Type" and open it from Android browser.

Comment: That would work, or putting it on a thumb drive, or I put my APKs in Dropbox and install it from there, or....  I love the openness of Android (can't image dealing with all that provisioning BS from iOS).

Comment: While Android APKs indeed can be distributed in whatever way, a service like TestFlight can still be *extemely useful* as a hassle-free approach to distribution. Also, using the SDK, you get simple analytics and automated crash reporting which I have found very valuable as well.

Comment: FYI, after TestFlight was bought by Apple, they announced they won't be supporting Android going forward.  We use AppInstall at work , and have luck with it.

Comment: The advantage of apps like TestFlight for larger apps is that it manages subscriptions of users, feedback notifications/downloads of new releases.  For smaller apps, your friends, early startups, just maintaining an email list / dropbox deep link is usually enough.

Answer (score 5):

**[HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/)** is one well-known TestFlight alternative.

<s>No first-hand experience, but</s> I will be evaluating HockeyApp now that TestFlight is officially [dropping Android support](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/02/apple-buys-testflight?utm_campaign=infoq_content&utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=feed&utm_term=global) (by 21 March 2014).

**Update**: I've since used HockeyApp for beta version distribution, and it works fine as TestFlight replacement. (Haven't tried the Android SDK for fancier features though.)

Some related blog resources:

- ["Why I moved to HockeyApp"](http://digitalflapjack.com/blog/2012/jun/19/hockeyapp/)
- ["I switched from TestFlight to HockeyApp recently and couldn’t be happier"](http://collindonnell.com/2012/05/28/hockeyapp-is-awesome/)

**[TestFairy](http://testfairy.com/)** is another interesting tool that came up in a [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/kaivirkki/status/437126525415342080) about TestFlight's Android discontinuation.

Comment: HockeyApp (acquired by MSFT) works pretty well for OS X apps.  Haven't tried it for Android apps.

Comment: Yeah, my answer was out of date; later I've used HockeyApp for Android apps and yep, it's decent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Appaloosa-Store**](http://www.appaloosa-store.com/)  for all Platforms

Especially,

```
Android    
iOS     
Windows Phone
```

**See the details** [here](http://www.appaloosa-store.com/)

[image]