# TestFlight for Android apps

Tags: android, testflight

TestFlight team has started Android service besides iOS one.

I am a bit reluctant into moving to TestFlight as Android testing system is pretty easy: build APK and distribute it to everyone. No UDIDs complications like when testing iOS.

Can someone tell me what are the pros and cons of switching to TestFlight for Android?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179318/testflight-alternatives-for-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We use testflight for IOS and Android.

Main Advantages for us:

- same process for IOS and android
- make distribution lists, control who you distribute your apps to

Disadvantage (for us):

- users need to create a testflight account
- the occasional service issue (slow upload/download, downtime, etc. It happens)

We send builds to testflight automatically (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Testflight+Plugin / disclaimer I maintain that plugin), and internally all our team members can access any version. In a distributed environment, with multiple products and versions it is very practical.

Comment: Upvote for effort. From the time I asked this question, we started using it as well :).

Comment: Apple bought burstly and therefore they stop supporting android, so this is soon not an option anymore...

Comment: Testflight is going to discontinue Android support. Official word [here](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1450414)

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/testflight/ suggests https://thebetafamily.com/  Does anyone have a good/preferred Android beta distribution app?  (See also duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179318/testflight-alternatives-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight says,

`Android developers and testers can now enjoy the benefits of TestFlight including beta management, distribution, tracking, and centralized feedback. TestFlight’s goal is to streamline the beta-testing process so developers can spend time building better apps versus building tools to manage their beta-testing.`

Comment: does your team uses it?